# Install and Set Up kubectl

Tags: kubectl

I just tried to install kubectl on macos, yet got warning at the end:

```
$ sudo gcloud components install kubectl
Password:


Your current Cloud SDK version is: 236.0.0
Installing components from version: 236.0.0

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                 These components will be installed.                 │
├─────────────────────┬────────────────────────┬──────────────────────┤
│         Name        │        Version         │         Size         │
├─────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ kubectl             │             2018.09.17 │              < 1 MiB │
│ kubectl             │                 1.10.7 │             12.8 MiB │
└─────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴──────────────────────┘

For the latest full release notes, please visit:
  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Creating update staging area                             ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: kubectl                                      ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: kubectl                                      ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Creating backup and activating new installation          ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

Performing post processing steps...done.                                                                                                                                                                                                     

Update done!

WARNING:   There are older versions of Google Cloud Platform tools on your system PATH.
  Please remove the following to avoid accidentally invoking these old tools:

  /usr/local/Cellar/kubernetes-cli/1.13.2/bin/kubectl


$
```

I'm not sure of why there are two of `kubectl` (different versions) or how does one removes old tool?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You installed one kubectl with gcloud, and one (in the Celler directory) with `brew install kubernetes-cli` as described by https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-with-homebrew-on-macos

You could remove the brew-provided kubectl with `brew remove kubernetes-cli` like https://superuser.com/questions/273966/how-can-i-uninstall-using-homebrew

Answer (score 0):

The one installed by brew maybe because of other dependencies too, for e.g.if u tried kubeless , that would have installed kubectl inside the brew directories. You could remove those or as the warning indicated, make sure the PATH doesnt include the Brew installed ones.